# Difference between $a=&$b , $a = $b and $a= clone $b in PHP OOP

Tags: php, class, reference, clone, copy-initialization

What is the difference between `$a = &$b`, `$a = $b` and `$b = clone $a` in PHP OOP? `$a` is an instance of a class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
// $a is a reference of $b, if $a changes, so does $b.    
$a = &$b; 

// assign $b to $a, the most basic assign.
$a = $b; 

// This is for object clone. Assign a copy of object `$b` to `$a`. 
// Without clone, $a and $b has same object id, which means they are pointing to same object.
$a = clone $b;
```

And check more info with [References](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php), [Object Cloning](http://jp.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php).

Comment: I was also writing almost the same! +1, although I wish you explained PHP referencing and cloning a bit more. Update: and of course you updated your answer same time I posted the comment :D

Comment: i don't understand exactly what is the main difference between $a = $b; and $a = &$b; If you look at the first example here http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php it gives the same result

Comment: @AnonimWd Yes, for objects, because use `$a = $b` will let they pointing to same object, but for other type, when you do `$a = $b`, change the value of `$a` will not affect `$b`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// $a has same object id as $b. if u set $b = NULL, $a would be still an object
$a = $b;

// $a is a link to $b. if u set $b = NULL, $a would also become NULL
$a = &$b;

// clone $b and store to $a. also __clone method of $b will be executed
$a = clone $b;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you didn't know what is ZVAL structure,and what is refcount,is_ref in ZVAL structure about,just take some time for [PHP's garbage collection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php).