# Object Copying and Evaluating $b = $a

Tags: php

My question is $b the same as $a in the output? Am I just passing a reference to $a when using ($b = $a)  and not making a copy of the object?

```
$a = new DateTime('2014-01-15');
$i = new DateInterval('P1D');
print $a->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;          // 2014-01-15
$b = $a;
print $a->add($i)->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL; // 2014-01-16
print $b->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;          // 2014-01-16
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the use of [`clone`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php):

```
$a = new DateTime('2014-01-15');
$i = new DateInterval('P1D');
print $a->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;          // 2014-01-15
$b = clone $a;                                // Here we clone the object
print $a->add($i)->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL; // 2014-01-16
print $b->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;          // 2014-01-15
```

Further explanation from the docs: `if your object holds a reference to another object which it uses and when you replicate the parent object you want to create a new instance of this other object so that the replica has its own separate copy.`  It sounds like just setting `$a = $b` will have the same initialization of the object, meaning if one changes the other does.  The variable `$b` becomes a sort of symbolic link to the initialized object held in `$a`.

Comment: I see, can you explain then what a simple $b = $a does then?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184743/difference-between-a-b-a-b-and-a-clone-b-in-php-oop Found a good explanation ! I will accept your answer asap. TY